# Where does the huntsman come from in the story of Snow White?

Tags: character, snow-white-and-the-huntsman

In [Snow White and the Huntsman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_White_and_the_Huntsman), Huntsman is the major character and his addition made the story as a love triangle. But my question is that is Huntsman part of the real Snow White's fairy tale or its only this movie which changes the story?

I know that the movie changed many aspects of the story but i don't remember of any Huntsman's character in the real snow white story. So is it its first appearance for a change or i missed any point of real story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a *Huntsman* in the [**original tale**](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Edash/grimm053.html):

> **Then [the queen] summoned a huntsman** and said to him, *"Take Snow-White out into the woods. I never want to see her again. Kill her, and as proof that she is dead bring her lungs and her liver back to me."*
>
> **The huntsman obeyed and took Snow-White into the woods.** He took out his hunting knife and was about to stab it into her innocent heart when she began to cry, saying, *"Oh, dear huntsman, let me live. I will run into the wild woods and never come back."*
>
> **Because she was so beautiful the huntsman took pity on her**, and he said, *"Run away, you poor child."*
>
> **He thought, *"The wild animals will soon devour you anyway,"*** but still it was as if a stone had fallen from his heart, for he would not have to kill her.
>
> Just then a young boar came running by. He killed it, cut out its lungs and liver, and took them back to the queen as proof of Snow-White's death.